# Array of Promises still say pending after chaining on then function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently working on a small express app where I am using axios to send/receive data from a github API. I am using insomnia to test sending the data as JSON to the github API in order to find specified user(s) profile information. This is how I am sending the data:

```
{
    "developers": ["person", "person"]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    let results = req.body.developers
    results.map(async d => {
      await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${d}`)
      .then((response => {
        console.log(response)
      }))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    })
      let out = results.map(r => ({ name: r.data.name, bio: r.data.bio }));
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(out));
```

When I make a request, I receive my promises in an array, but they still say 'Pending'. I thought that by chaining the `then` function to my get request within the `results.map` would solve this issue. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You're missing an `await Promise.all` on `results.map` - you get an array of promises back but never actually wait for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `await Promise.all()` on `results`, and assign the responses to some variable to use in your `out` array.

```
const results = req.body.developers
const responses = await Promise.all(results.map(async d => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${d}`);
    console.log(response);
    return response;
});
const out = responses.map(({ data } => ({ name: data.name, bio: data.bio }));
return res.send(JSON.stringify(out));
```

For error handling, you can wrap the Promise.all call in a try/catch block, and handle the rejected promise there.